# number of combinations of numbers 1 to 12

Tags: combinatorics

I have 12 couples meeting for dinner each week in groups of 4.
       How many times can they meet without any couple meeting twice?
        Is there a table I could use to figure all the combinations?

Comment: Groups of 4 couples or 4 individuals?

Answer (score 0):

From the title, I'm assuming you mean there are $4$ couples in each group. In this case, you can only do one week without any pair of couples meeting twice.

In the first week, we have $3$ groups of $4$. In the next week, if we consider any of our $3$ new groups, by pigeonhole principle at least two of the couples must have been in the same group the previous week.